# CSS Selector for zebra styling with a break in between

Tags: css

I have a html table with many rows representing business data. Every data item is contained in two rows and I want to do zebra styling where both rows are styled similiar but not identical.

I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e142owja/4/) for this. The text in the rows represents the wish of the final outcome, the background color is what I currently have.

The table is as simple as can be:

```
<table>
  <tr class="data"><td>green</td></tr>
  <tr class="data"><td>dark green</td></tr>
  <tr class="data"><td>blue</td></tr>
  <tr class="data"><td>dark blue</td></tr>
  <tr><td><h3>This is a header with no background color</h3></td></tr>
  <tr class="data"><td>green (should continue zebra backgrounds)</td></tr>
  <tr class="data"><td>dark green</td></tr>
  <tr class="data"><td>blue</td></tr>
  <tr class="data"><td>dark blue</td></tr>
</table>
```

and the css selectors to get the current result are:

```
tr.data:nth-of-type(4n+1) { background-color: green;}
tr.data:nth-of-type(4n+2) { background-color: darkgreen;}
tr.data:nth-of-type(4n+3) { background-color: blue;}
tr.data:nth-of-type(4n+4) { background-color: darkblue;}
```

[image: current render result]

The part I cannot get working is the backgrounds after the inbetween header row.

The data rows are always a multiple of two but their actual number before and after the header is not static.

---

My only <del>solution</del> *hack* is to insert a second zero-height row in the inbetween header row and call it good enough, but can i do better?

Comment: This can't be solved this easily, for now at least...

Comment: the duplicate is actually answering, that it is not possible (now). I am back to rendering more css classes based on the item number on each tr and styling it that way.

Comment: You could use something called `<tbody>` for the special row. It is valid HTMLTable element, that will not match `table>tr:nth-of-type()` selector

Comment: i would have used thead, but it is only allowed once per table. and i am not sure wether you are allowed to have TRs and tbody as sibblings of a table.

Comment: It is not true: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). "zero or more <tbody> elements"
https://jsfiddle.net/uxxL64go/

Comment: its true "an optional <tfoot> element, either before or after **one of the following**:
zero or more <tbody> elements
one or more <tr> elements"

Comment: you can have tr either directly under table or you can have a tbody in between but you must not mix both ways

Comment: True, but the selector will work, if you only wrap headers in `tbody`, as HTML parsers will autocomplete other `tbody` there too. Or if you can, you can place `tbody` everywhere.